# How to change Default answer No QnAMaker answers found in Azure qnamaker

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I have choosen Nodejs in Azure Webapp bot with Qnamaker and Default No answer modified in online code editor itself, but still it is not reflecting in chat. Even I tried changing the Default answer in app service configuration its not working

[image: chatsnapshot]

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Can you expand your question with screenshots of where in the app service configuration and the online code editor you changed it? I think I have a solution, but want to make sure it's the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the nodeJs code and change the text.

in "dialogs/qnamakerBaseDialog.js"

You can do:

```
class QnAMakerBaseDialog extends QnAMakerDialog {
/**
 * Core logic of QnA Maker dialog.
 * @param {QnAMaker} qnaService A QnAMaker service object.
 */
constructor(knowledgebaseId, authkey, host) {

    var noAnswer = DefaultNoAnswer;
    var filters = [];
    super(knowledgebaseId, authkey, host, noAnswer, DefaultThreshold, DefaultCardTitle, DefaultCardNoMatchText,
        DefaultTopN, ActivityFactory.cardNoMatchResponse, filters, QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG);
    this.id = QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG;
}
```

}

Take note that:

```
 var noAnswer = DefaultNoAnswer;
```

And / OR you can change the default message in line 15 (or so)

```
const DefaultNoAnswer = 'Your custom message';
```